# UPDATE Statement not working. what's wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm SORRY everyone, It wasn't allowing me to comment. you are right. It's the ALTER I'm having issues with. How do I add the Cumulative GPA column to the table (using the alter statement) where the gpa is displayed between 0.00 and 4.00

```
CREATE database "IS4440_DuBoseJasmine"

CREATE TABLE StudentInformation (
StudentID               CHAR(7) not null,
StudentSSN              CHAR(9) null,
StudentFirstName        VARCHAR(50) null,
StudentLastName         VARCHAR(50) null,
StudentMiddleName       VARCHAR(50) null,
StudentHomeCountry      CHAR(2) not null
)
/*2*/
ALTER TABLE StudentInformation ADD Cumulative GPA ;

/*3*/
INSERT INTO StudentInformation (StudentID, StudentLastName, StudentFirstName,     StudentMiddleName,     StudentHomeCountry)
VALUES ('1352154', 'DuBose', 'Jasmine', 'Leigh', 'US')
INSERT INTO StudentInformation (StudentID, StudentLastName, StudentFirstName, StudentMiddleName, StudentHomeCountry)
VALUES ('1234565', 'Smith', 'Johnny', 'Apple', 'GB');
/*4*/
UPDATE StudentInformation SET StudentSSN = 123456789
WHERE StudentID = 1352154;
```

Comment: Since the fields are `CHAR` types, you might try putting the values you're using in the `UPDATE` in single quotes like you used in the `INSERT`

Comment: What isn't working? The `UPDATE` statement works fine. It is the `ALTER TABLE` that fails.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: You tried to run your query ? It's working your `ALTER Table` statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The update works fine ([demonstrated on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b36d/1)), it is the ALTER TABLE statement that fails. This line:

```
ALTER TABLE StudentInformation ADD Cumulative GPA;
```

should be:

```
ALTER TABLE StudentInformation ADD [Cumulative GPA] INT -- OR WHATEVER TYPE IT SHOULD BE;
```

**[ALTER TABLE Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)**

As an aside, although this may just be an example, if it isn't you will want to `USE` your database before you create the table:

```
CREATE database "IS4440_DuBoseJasmine";
GO
USE IS4440_DuBoseJasmine;

CREATE TABLE ...
```

Otherwise you will just be creating your table in whatever database you are connected to.

Comment: Yes everyone I have updated the question. I am so sorry, somehow it logged me out and I couldn't figure out how to comment on the post. The problem is the ALTER statement not the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is fine, Your ALTER statement what fails, You are adding new column to your table without any datatype or constrains, try this to alter your table

You can use `Numeric(3,2)` or `Decimal(3,2)`, that means total three digits two after decimal point so a max of `9.99` .

```
 ALTER TABLE StudentInformation ADD CumulativeGPA Numeric(3,2) NULL
```

To alter your table to add new column make that column `NULLABLE` and while naming your column do not give spaces.

To make column type Not Nullable

```
ALTER TABLE StudentInformation ALTER COLUMN CumulativeGPA  DECIMAL(3,2) NULL ;
```